# How to filter values for multiple data using reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to react and want to make search filter for multiple data in the object. I've tried for filtering single data, code is as shown below:

```
    var {Data, search} =this.state;
            search = this.state.search.trim().toLowerCase();
        if (search.length > 0) {
          Data= Data.filter(function(i) {
            return i.firstName.toLowerCase().match( search );

          });
        }
```

It is working great but only for the firstName. But my objective is to get filter for lastName, Location and Skills also.

Here is the code:

```
export default class DataView extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      Data: [],
      search: ""
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData();
  }
  fetchData() {
    fetch("api/Profile")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({
          Data: data.item1
        });
      });
  }
  handleSearch = e => {
    this.setState({ search: e.target.value });
  };

  render() {
    var { Data, search } = this.state;
    search = this.state.search.trim().toLowerCase();
    if (search.length > 0) {
      Data = Data.filter(function(i) {
        return i.firstName.toLowerCase().match(search);
      });
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <Segment className="p_segment">
          <Input
            icon="search"
            placeholder="Search..."
            className="a_Search"
            value={this.state.search}
            onChange={this.handleSearch}
          />
        </Segment>

        <Container className="p_view">
          {Data.map(View => {
            return (
              <Grid key={View.id}>
                <Grid.Row className=" p_header">
                  <Checkbox className="p_checkbox" />
                  <Header>
                    {" "}
                    {View.firstName} {View.lastName}{" "}
                  </Header>
                </Grid.Row>
                <Divider className="p_divider" />
                <Grid.Row>
                  <Icon name="marker" /> {View.location}
                  <Divider className="p_divider" />
                </Grid.Row>
                <Grid.Row>
                  <Grid.Column>
                    <div>
                      <div className="g_column">
                        {View.skillset.map(data => {
                          return (
                            <Label className="c_label">{data.skill}</Label>
                          );
                        })}
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </Grid.Column>
                </Grid.Row>
              </Grid>
            );
          })}
        </Container>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Can anyone help me in this Query?

Comment: Is skillset an array and you would like to search in this array too?

Comment: Could you please create working sample??

Comment: @Agney - Yes Correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply make an OR statement

```
return i.firstName.toLowerCase().match( search ) || i.skills.toLowerCase().match( search ) || i.location.toLowerCase().match( search );
```

Or if you want to search the full object

```
return JSON.stringify(i).toLowerCase().match(search);
```

Comment: @Sandhya : accepting above answer is an extremely poor choice - first suggested solution will turn into the dumb lump of OR chained conditions if you need to check 5, 10, 15 props; second option is outright wrong - it will match not only property values but property names just as well, so, whenever you search for some string that partially matches your key name, you'll get the entire array instead of proper match. I don't even speak performance (but even for 3 records above solution [may result](https://jsbench.me/52k89d2xqz/1) into 20% performance loss, imagine 100 records, 1000...

Answer (score 1):

If case-insensitive partial match across the object values is what you've been after, you may simply extract [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) into an array and make use of [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) together with `Array.prototype.filter()` in a similar way to what you did:

```js
const stateData = [{
          firstName: 'Stephen',
          lastName: 'Smith',
          location: 'Johannesburg',   //match by location
          skills: 'golf'
        },{
          firstName: 'George',
          lastName: 'Washington',
          location: 'Philadelphia',
          skills: 'majohng'           //match by skills
        },{
          firstName: 'Dummy',
          lastName: 'Dummyson',
          location: 'Dummywille',
          skills: 'dummy'
      }],
      searchString = 'jo',
      
      searchResult = stateData.filter(record => 
        Object
          .values(record)
          .some(prop => 
            prop
              .toLowerCase()
              .includes(searchString.toLowerCase())
           )
       )
        
console.log(searchResult)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some notation.

```
var { Data, search } = this.state; // don't use var
    search = this.state.search.trim().toLowerCase(); // don't do mutation
    if (search.length > 0) {
      Data = Data.filter(function(i) { // don't do mutation
        return i.firstName.toLowerCase().match(search);
      });
    }
```

1. Add `result` to state.
2. use [componentDidUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate).
3. check if the `search` filed was changed.
4. do filter.
5. reset `result` if the `search` field empty.

```js
import React from "react";

export default class DataView extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      search: "",
      result: [], // [1]
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData();
  }
  
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) { // [2]
    const { search: prevSearch } = prevState;
    const { search: nextSearch, data } = this.state;
    
    if (prevSearch !== nextSearch) { // [3]
      const trimed = nextSearch.trim().toLowerCase();
      const result = nextSearch.length > 0
      ? data.filter(({ firstName, lastName }) => ( // [4]
        `${firstName} ${lastName}`.toLowerCase().includes(trimed)
      ))
      : []; // [5]
      
      this.setState({ result });
    }
  }

  fetchData() {
    fetch("api/Profile")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(({ item1 }) => {
        this.setState({ data: item1 });
      });
  }
  handleSearch = (e) => {
    this.setState({ search: e.target.value });
  };

  render() {
    const { data, search, result } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <Segment className="p_segment">
          <Input
            icon="search"
            placeholder="Search..."
            className="a_Search"
            value={search}
            onChange={this.handleSearch}
          />
        </Segment>

        <Container className="p_view">
          {result.map((view) => {
            const {
              id,
              firstName,
              lastName,
              location,
              skillset,
            } = view;
            
            return (
              <Grid key={id}>
                <Grid.Row className=" p_header">
                  <Checkbox className="p_checkbox" />
                  <Header>
                    {` ${firstName} ${lastName} `}
                  </Header>
                </Grid.Row>
                <Divider className="p_divider" />
                <Grid.Row>
                  <Icon name="marker" /> {location}
                  <Divider className="p_divider" />
                </Grid.Row>
                <Grid.Row>
                  <Grid.Column>
                    <div>
                      <div className="g_column">
                        {skillset.map(({ skill }) => (
                          <Label className="c_label">{skill}</Label>
                        ))}
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </Grid.Column>
                </Grid.Row>
              </Grid>
            );
          })}
        </Container>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```